# symfony 1.4 FORMS - how to replace default (related) dropdown field by code generated in module / component?

Tags: forms, symfony1

I've been creating with a ajax and doctrine chain-dropdown to select a category. I put them in component. It works like this:

> http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/ajax_drop_down_list.php

Im trying to replace default category dropdown build on schema and related with current table. When in

```
/lib/form/doctrine/TabbleForm.class.php
```

I remove a field with code:

```
unset($this['category']);
```

And in the tamplate which has a form body I paste a component code (with this dynamic ajax-based dropdown):

```
include_component('add', 'selectcategory',array('catid' => 0));
```

I have notice:

```
Unexpected extra form field named "category".
```

How can I replace that default code with category-field code from component / module?

Answer (score 0):

How do you display your form in the template? Using a basic `<?php echo $form; ?>` or manually like:

```
<?php echo $form['field']->renderLabel() ?>
<?php echo $form['field']->render() ?>
<?php echo $form['field']->renderError() ?>
```

I suggest you to use the second method, at least using `<?php echo $form['field']->renderRow() ?>`. This way, you won't have to `unset` the categoy field from your Form class. But you will have to name the select tag in your component the same way the form do.

If the form display:

```
<select id="formname_category" name="formname[category]">...</select>
```

You will have to use the same name (for the second select I guess). Then, you won't have any problem in your form and, more important, the validator related to your `category` field will also work!